# block/restrict/Provide access to IP range in SP 2013

Tags: 2013

We have Internet facing site in SharePoint Online, we want to block some IP range and we want to provide access to certain IP range and also we want to restrict some IP range. Is it possible in SharePoint Online? or in in Windows AZURE (On-Premise)?

Answer (score 0):

There is very good article from Microsoft Which show how you can block and grant access to certain IP through IIS.

I hope this will help you.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324066

Comment: If you spot a duplicate question, please flag it as a duplicate instead of making a duplicate answer.